# How to read properties file in Install4j - example appreciated

Tags: java, install4j

I have a properties file that basically looks like this:

```
version.major=2
version.minor=1
version.revision=3
```

And am trying to read in all 3 pieces of information using the "Read a properties file" action. The information area says the following of the variable:

> The name of the variable that will be set with an instance of
> java.util.Map.

There is no "map" variable type in Install4j. Are we supposed to declare a single variable of type "array" like "string array" and then loop through it and set 3 discrete variables? Is there a way to leverage the array as a map throughout the installer so as to avoid helper variables like this (simply look up each key/value pair as needed)? I feel like I'm missing something.

Here's the script I'm currently using. I have read the properties into a string array called BUILD and use this to set the "major" variable (which I repeat for "minor" and "revision").

```
final String key = "version.major";
String[] arr = (String[])context.getVariable("BUILD");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].startsWith(key)) {
        return arr[i].substring(arr[i].indexOf('=') + 1).trim();
    }
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1 - **Create your own [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class extension:** (optional)

```
public class ConfigProperties extends Properties 
{       
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Integer readMandatoryInteger(String key) throws IOException
    {
       String value = getProperty(key);
       if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
          throw new IOException(String.format("Insert missing config: %s.",key));
        
       return Integer.parseInt(value);
    }       

    //readMandatoryString, and so on....

    public String getKey(String prefix, String key)
    {
        String value = key;
        if (prefix != null && !prefix.isEmpty())
            value = prefix + "." + key;
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is the simplest example I could get, you can add a function for reading Longs, Strings, Booleans, or whatever.

### 2- Initialize your properties entity and read the file:

```
ConfigProperties props = new ConfigProperties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile));
```

### 3- Read from your properties instance:

You can just retrieve the values by key.

```
int majorv = props.readMandatoryInteger("version.major"); 

System.out.print(majorv); // 2
```

---

You can also print/show key and values, just:

- [`list(PrintStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#list(java.io.PrintStream))

*Prints this property list out to the specified output stream.*

```
props.list(System.out);
```

---

Or you could get an `Enumeration` of the keys, in order to be retrieved by the first shown read operation:

- [`propertyNames()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames())

*Returns an enumeration of all the keys in this property list, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list.***

```
 nameEnums = props.propertyNames();
```

---

### Create a `getter` method in your extended `Properties` class

You could use your extended `Properties` class and create a method that returns a `HashMap`, or desired structure, that stores your property file keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no "map" variable type in Install4j.

This is the `java.util.Map` from the standard library in the JDK. The action does not create installer variables for each entry in the properties file. I've added this idea for a new action to our issue tracker.

Assuming you have set the "Variable name" property of the "Read a properties file" action to "**propertyMap**", add a "Run script" action after it and set its "Script" property to

```
    Map<String, String> propertyMap = (Map<String, String>)context.getVariable("propertyMap");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
        context.setVariable(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return true;
```

Then each property in the properties file will be saved as an installer variable and you can use the variables with the syntax

```
${installer:version.major}
```

in text field properties of subsequent screens, actions and form components.